# Connecting to remote mysql database using HTTPS URL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a sourceforge hosted MySQL database and the connection URL is as follows:

```
https://mysql-t.sourceforge.net:3306/"db_name"
```

I want to use JDBC to connect to this database.
My connection URL is as follows:

```
jdbc:mysql://https://mysql-t.sourceforge.net:3306
```

However, I keep getting the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Must specify port after ':' in connection string
```

The reason for this, I believe, is that the `https://` part keeps expecting a port after the `:` sign, like `https://<port#>`

I could probably use `getInetAddress()` to retrieve the IP and use that, but I need a better solution since that might not be right.

Comment: https:// indicates that an SSL connection should be established on port 443, and subsequent traffic will be HTTP content. This has nothing whatsoever to do with a MySQL connection. Drop the `https://` from your url and try again. Be aware that this will **not** be a secure connection

Comment: I have tried just that, but it gives me a 
`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Comment: If you can't telnet to that server and port, JDBC won't be able to connect, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed.

1) The access URL is different from what was provided. I found that out from the sourceforge forums where other users had similar problems.

2) The port number is different. It works at 4040 and not 3306.

3) Sourceforge apparently doesn't allow permanent access to their database. It works only on request and only for 4 hours at a time. They do not allow using their database as backend.

Answer (score 4):

Your URL should not include http or https.  Try it like [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html):

```
jdbc:mysql://mysql-t.sourceforge.net:3306/db_name
```

You might be thinking that you have to include http or https because port 3306 is not visible to your client on the Internet. Be glad that it's not.  If it's visible to you, it's visible everyone else, too.

You need an intermediary servlet between your client and the database.  Clients can contact the servlet via http port 80 or https port 443.  The servlet will authenticate and authorize them, validate and bind parameters, make requests to the database on their behalf, and send the appropriate response.

You should not be letting anyone use the root or admin credentials to access that database.  You should create credentials just for that app, accessing only one database, allowing only the operations needed to do the job.

Comment: This particular database gives only SELECT permissions to the user, so that way I think the risk is mitigated.
That way, Sourceforge is awesome because it gives me separate usernames and passwords depending on access levels.